# Как сделать колонки на всю высоту вместе с футером всегда внизу?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Есть вот такой макет: [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/NicBird/pen/XzKVQX)

```html
<div class="middle">
  <div class="primary">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Контент</br>
    Вот такие пироги
  </div>
  <div class="secondary">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Сколько я не мучался, не могу сделать, чтобы колонки всегда были по высоте на всю страницу. То одна из них пропадает, то футер накладывается на них после прокрутки, то они вообще перестают быть колонками. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Может есть готовый шаблон?

Comment: Что значит вместе с футером?

Comment: Скрины есть. Вот при малом контенте http://prntscr.com/h6uqeb

Comment: Вот если много контента http://prntscr.com/h6uqsb Футер в данном случае... Ну, вы видите как себя ведет

Comment: Это где нужно менять, в изначальном коде?

Comment: Скиньте пожалуйста код, который на вашем первом скриншоте. Это то, что мне и нужно, если footer при большом количестве контента еще нормально себя ведет

Comment: Да, чтобы до него надо было листать когда много контента, но при этом колонки должны быть всегда до начала футера (в полную высоту). На первом вашем скриншоте то, что мне нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
body {
    margin:0;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.middle {
    flex-grow: 3;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.primary {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 20%;
}
.content {
    flex-grow: 2;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.secondary {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: green;
}
    .footer {
        height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid;
        border: 1px solid;
        align-items: : flex-end;
    }
```

Учите flex-box

Comment: Не помогло... Как у вас на скриншоте не получается, пустые места между колонками, страница прокручивается даже при маленьком количестве контента

Comment: У меня все работает. Я использовал тот html, который Вы предоставили в вопросе.  Может быть он вырван из контекста и у Вас еще есть какая-то разметка? Или скопировали не все?

Comment: Я меняю код прямо в CodePen.io Не знаю с чем связана проблема. А .secondary не надо менять?

Comment: aaa... secondary забыл - добавил secondary в код. ширину блоков зададите по своему усмотрению.
П.С. но отсутствие secondary сути особо не меняло. Можно еще кучу колонок добавить - все будет норм.

Comment: Посмотрите мой Codepen, что я сделал не так?

Comment: Посмотрел. Футер  всегда внизу, колонки на всю высоту. Как Вы и просили. Или Вы не этого хотели?

Comment: Появились белые отступы. Футер всегда внизу, и даже больше внизу, чем надо, страницу приходиться прокручивать даже при малом количестве контента http://prntscr.com/h6v13r

Comment: Добавьте в CodePen: body {     min-height: 100%; }

Comment: Если поставить height: auto; футер уже не внизу. А белые полоски по краям экрана так и остались...

Comment: Белые отступы - это маржины, которые браузер добавляет автоматически. Установите для `body` `margin:0`.
Страницу приходится прокручивать, потом что высота ее 1500px. Играйтесь с ней, если слишком высоко. Сделайте ее резиновой.  В первоначальном вопросе о желаемой высоте Вы ничего не упоминали.

Comment: Ответ должен быть адаптивным, как мне кажется

Comment: ок. Вместо `body {  height: 1500px;}`  напишите `body {min-height:желаемая высота;}`

Футер будет всегда внизу.

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение проблемы! Я не упомянул высоту, потому что считал, что все сейчас делают "резину". Все работает как надо, добавил в body { margin: 0; min-height: 100%; }

Comment: Измените строку в данном ответе на body { margin: 0; min-height: 100%; } И ответ будет рабочим